# Filter Object by it's values

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to filter an array of objects based on them objects having a value which partially matches a string.

```
const acceptedValues = "theme";
const myObject = {
  code: "themev3",
}

var filteredObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (acceptedValues.indexOf(myObject[e].toLowerCase()) >= 0) r[e] = myObject[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(filteredObject);
```

As you can see the object above should be returned in the `filteredObject` array as `code` has got `theme` in it.

This is not working however, any ideas why?

Comment: It's `haystack.indexOf(needle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the searched text and search from text. Over here you need to check whether `myObject[e]` has any part of the `acceptedValues`

```js
const acceptedValues = "theme";
const myObject = {
  code: "themev3",
}

var filteredObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (myObject[e].toLowerCase().indexOf(acceptedValues) >= 0) r[e] = myObject[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(filteredObject);
```

Also, you can use `includes` in place of `indexOf` like following

```
if(myObject[e].toLowerCase().includes(acceptedValues))
```

Comment: @MartynBall - Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the switching comparison, you could map the key/value pairs and build new objects after filtering.

```js
const
    value = "theme",
    object = { code: "themev3" },
    filtered = Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .entries(object)
            .filter(([, v]) => v.toLowerCase().includes(value))
            .map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }))
    );

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be reverse. You need to find the index of `acceptedValues` in the object values instead:

```js
const acceptedValues = "theme";

const myObject = {
  code: "themev3",
}

var filteredObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (myObject[e].toLowerCase().indexOf(acceptedValues.toLowerCase()) > -1)
    r[e] = myObject[e];
    
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(filteredObject);
```